# TYPO3 TreeLevel and FLUID - empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-11.x

my output is a simple MenuProcessor like this:

```
tt_content.content_element_overview_navigation =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.content_element_overview_navigation {
  templateName = OverviewNavigation
  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    10 {
      special = directory
      special.value.field = pages

      dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
          references.fieldName = media
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the Fluid Output work also fine:

```
lib.overviewContentNavigation = COA
lib.overviewContentNavigation {
    20 = COA
    20 =< tt_content.content_element_overview_navigation
}
```

**Fluid Output:**

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.overviewContentNavigation" />
```

**But now, i need the output only in the treeLevel 5.**
My Test:

```
[tree.level == 5]
  lib.overviewContentNavigation = COA
  lib.overviewContentNavigation {
    20 = COA
    20 =< tt_content.content_element_overview_navigation
  }
[end]
```

If the tree.level / typoscriptObjectPath is empty, then I get an error in the frontend.
How can i check the empty output?

**Dont work:**

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.overviewContentNavigation')}">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.overviewContentNavigation" />
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the object path every time, so only add the content when condition is met. I would give this a try:

```
lib.overviewContentNavigation = COA
lib.overviewContentNavigation.20 = COA

[tree.level == 5]
lib.overviewContentNavigation {
  20 =< tt_content.content_element_overview_navigation
}
[end]
```

Comment: big thanks! That works, and yes, it is also understandable ;)